# SVPWM board testing for design and development

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb, power-electronics, induction-motor, vector-control

I am trying to test the current feedback of my SVPWM board. For safety, I am thinking of connecting a light bulb instead of a PMSM motor. One incandescent light bulb across the U-V phase and nothing else. I will measure and read the current produced on my TM4C1249 controller.

As a first step for my development, is this okay? Will connecting only one bulb instead of three cause any problems to my PCB?

Comment: The resistance of a light bulb is not constant and may be confusing to interpret. Back when I had some firmware guys who kept blowing up 500$ motors with bad code I gave them a piece of wood with three inductors and three power resistors until they got everything working - cheap and easy

Comment: Wow, that is a great idea. So simple. Thanks. I will do that too. :)